# Bug in careers Stack Overflow on click of print profile at top right?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just noticed that if you try to click the print icon (Print Profile) on  the top right corner, located slightly near the image of persons' profile. The page will open in new window and ask you to login. Now if you  return to the profile page which redirect you to login page, it just has blank content. The address bar basically tries to load the pop up using window.open. It returns

```
javascript:window.open('/cv/19636/print-preview')
```

Error for this page:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jonskeet

Comment: For me it's opening new tab at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/19636/print-preview which gives "Page Not Found".

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug, let me check in with @WillCole and see exactly how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I have the spec and will get this fixed up sometime this afternoon.

Comment: @NickLarsen: thats great, though I am not a recruiter looking for peoples profiles, but Bug like this on Stack Exchange sounds extremely unusual.

Answer (score 2):

This was a permission issue and is now fixed. If you can see the profile, you can print it.